# migrating from Solr 5.2 to Solr 8.2 -- query using edismax not yielding results

Tags: solr, edismax

I am trying the following query from solr:

```
    http://localhost:8393/solr/core-name/select?defType=edismax&fl=product_id_i,ProductName_ten&q=cnmg+432+ud32&q.op=AND&qf=ProductName_ten_ngram
```

On Solr 5.2, I get one document returned with the following results:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fl">product_id_i,ProductName_ten</str>
<str name="q">cnmg 432 ud32</str>
<str name="qf">ProductName_ten_ngram</str>
<str name="q.op">AND</str>
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<int name="product_id_i">1521210</int>
<str name="ProductName_ten">
CNMG 432 ZM1 UD32, 1/32″ Corner Radius, 3/16″ Thick, 1/2″ Inscribed Circle, Turning Indexable Insert
</str>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

On Solr 8.2, however, the document is not found, and I get the following results:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"cnmg 432 ud32",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "qf":"ProductName_ten_ngram",
      "fl":"product_id_i,ProductName_ten",
      "q.op":"AND"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

The schema.xml files for both systems are essentially identical, and the fields are defined as follows:

```
<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="ProductName_ten_ngram" type="text_gen_text_only_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
<dynamicField name="*_ten"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" />
<fieldType name="text_gen_text_only_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-z0-9.\/]" replacement="" replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" tokenSeparator="-"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-z0-9.\/]" replacement="" replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" tokenSeparator="-"/>
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="english" />
        <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory" managed="english" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

<copyField source="ProductName_ten" dest="ProductName_ten_ngram"/>
```

The question is -- why are results that are returned in Solr 5.2 not returned in Solr 8.2?

Comment: Do you see the terms you expect if you look at the field under the Solr admin? Do you get any entries if you facet on the field?

Comment: If, instead of querying via the search, I query fq=product_id_i: 1521210
then I do get the solr document with 
ProductName_ten: "CNMG 432 ZM1 UD32, 1/32″ Corner Radius, 3/16″ Thick, 1/2″ Inscribed Circle, Turning Indexable Insert"

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't tell us anything about how the `ProductName_ten_ngram` has been processed. Your first query already shows that the document has been indexed as you'd expect. However, your field contains a `KeywordTokenizer` and there is no ngramming taking place (you do not have any ngram filters in your chain). What do you expect to happen? The only thing indexed in that field is single, long tokens as far as I can tell that contain the complete text of the field.

Comment: I see I was missing part of the field type definition in my exert from the schema.  edited it in.  It does indeed include ngram under the "index" analyzer.

Comment: Then use the Analysis page under Solr admin and enter the indexed content and your query, and see why the generated tokens doesn't match - the stemming might be one of the issues here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like solr 5.2 and solr 8.2 reads the schema differently and there is a  conflict with the explicit field name = 'text_gen_text_only_ngram' and the dynamic field name = 'text_en_ngram' analyzer